# Difference between [行く末]{ゆくすえ}, 将来{しょうらい} and 未来{みらい}

Tags: word-choice, usage, synonyms

I've been looking around and I got that the three words can mean "future". Is there a way to differentiate them? Can they be used the same way?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

未来 and 将来 are pretty similar to each other. 大辞泉 breaks down the differences [under the 用法 section of 「将来」 entry](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/110409/m0u/%E5%B0%86%E6%9D%A5/) (explanation translated):

> 将来 and 未来 can both be used in situations where you're talking about
>   the time that will come after the present, e.g. 「将来（未来）への夢」 ("dreams
>   for the future") and 「明るい将来（未来）」 ("a bright future"). 「未来」 cannot be
>   used instead of 「将来」 in an expression like 「私は将来、弁護士になりたい」 ("in the
>   future, I want to be a lawyer"). Also, it's awkward to use 「将来」 in an
>   expression like 「二〇〇年後の未来を空想する」 ("imagine a future 200 years ahead of
>   now"). If it was only 10 years later, 「将来」 would be more common. 「未来」
>   has a strong sense of a more distinct, intangible future. 「近い将来」 is a
>   common expression, but 「近い未来」 is hardly ever said. The term
>   「近未来（きんみらい）」 is a recently-coined expression.

To summarize: they're very similar, but when used as an adverb, it's almost invariably 将来, not 未来, and 未来 by default has a farther-off, less tangible connotation.

As for 行く末, it's less common and seems to me to be a more personal sort of future. But I'd stick with 将来 and 未来 for almost all contexts.

Answer (score 16):

I was always taught that `将来【しょうらい】` was a more "tangible" future (like 5 years in the future, 10 years in the future, etc.), whereas `未来【みらい】` was more "intagible", "unknown", and "fantastical" (like "In the future, people will inhabit the moon"; like how people of the 50's thought life in 2000 would be).

I've never heard of `行【ゆ】く末【すえ】` until now, but it seems to correspond to my above definition of `未来【みらい】`; more far-off and unknown.

Comment: [行]{ゆ}く[末]{すえ} ='one's future'. [前途]{ぜんと}. e.g. 息子の行く末が心配だ (I'm anxious about my son's future.)/息子の行く末を見届けるまでは死ねない (I cannot die before I see how my son will turn out.) 行く末 sounds a bit literary I think...

Answer (score 9):

Literally they should roughly mean:

**将**来 - That which is **about to** come

**未**来　- That which has **not yet** come

This corresponds to the other answers here that indicates that `将来` is a more "tangible" future and `未来` being "intangible". Because for `将来` its path is approaching you. Compare with `未来` which isn't approaching you, in fact its kanji indicates that it will not yet come.