# difference of 将来(しょうらい) and 未来 (みらい)

Tags: word-choice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between ゆくすえ, しょうらい and みらい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4332/difference-between-%e3%82%86%e3%81%8f%e3%81%99%e3%81%88-%e3%81%97%e3%82%87%e3%81%86%e3%82%89%e3%81%84-and-%e3%81%bf%e3%82%89%e3%81%84)

Is there any difference between these two words? I first came across 未来 in a PS3 game (FFXIII-2) and after a bit of digging, I found it in a manga and also some songs. So I get the feeling that 未来 is used more in fictional material or art. Is my theory correct? Though I get the feeling that Im badly mistaken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

未来 is the more general term. 将来 is about future with particular focus on someone's carrier in life, or a master plan of some institution, place, product, etc.